# Dropzone max file size exceeded event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone in my form for image upload. I would like to show an alert message and remove the file added when the user chooses a file above the configured limit.
Here is my configuration:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = { 
      paramName: 'file',
      url: "http://someurl",
      clickable: true,
      enqueueForUpload: true,
      autoProcessQueue: false,
      uploadMultiple: true,
      parallelUploads: 5,
      maxFiles: 1,
      maxFilesize: .06,
      maxThumbnailFilesize: .06,
      acceptedMimeTypes: 'image/*',
      addRemoveLinks: true,
      dictDefaultMessage: 'Drag your images here',
      init: function() {
           console.log('init');
           this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
                alert("No more files please!");
                this.removeFile(file);
            });

    }
};
```

I tried to register a listener for 'maxfilesizeexceeded' event, but it didnt fire.
I would like to take similar action as for 'maxfilesexceeded'.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have just tried it out on my script using the Error event. This way I get an Error Message and the File gets removed again. Is this what you are looking for?

```
    this.on("error", function(file, message) { 
                alert(message);
                this.removeFile(file); 
    });
```

Comment: Just be careful : the "error" event gets triggerred too, before the "maxfilesexceeded" event. If "error" event is not defined, then only "maxfilesexceeded" get triggerred. I recommend to always chek what is the "message" parameter of the "error" event.
Side note : the "error" event gets a third parameter "xhr", that is typeof 'undefined' when the error does not occur during request, and that is typeof 'object' when error occurs during upload (typically a Internal Error 500 server-side).